# SAS libname within macro

Tags: sas

I am trying to use a libname within macro, but it is generating a lot of errors.

```
libname result 'G';

%macro datain(yr);

data dc_&yr;
set result.dc_&yr;
end;

%mend datain;
```

Error

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable YR resolves to 2014
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable YR resolves to 2014
161: LINE and COLUMN cannot be determined.
NOTE: NOSPOOL is on. Rerunning with OPTION SPOOL might allow recovery of the LINE and COLUMN
      where the error has occurred.
ERROR 161-185: No matching DO/SELECT statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `run;` to end your data step. You wrote `end;` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I did not see that at all.